# Remove appendix chapters from TOC. Only keep Appendix in TOC

Tags: appendices, report

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage[toc]{appendix}
\titleformat{\chapter}[display] {\normalfont\Huge\bfseries}{\chaptertitlename\ \thechapter}{0pt}{\Huge}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\linespread{1.5}   
\usepackage[a4paper,top=3cm,bottom=2cm,left=3cm,right=3cm,marginparwidth=1.75cm]{geometry}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[colorinlistoftodos]{todonotes}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tocbibind}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
  colorlinks=false,
  urlbordercolor=red
}
\makeatletter

\xpatchcmd{\titlepage}{\thispagestyle{empty}}{\pagestyle{plain}}{}{}% \xpatchcmd{\endtitlepage}{\setcounter{page}\@ne}{\cleardoublepage}{}{}% Remove the reset of page at the end of titlepage

\newcommand\frontmatter{%
  \cleardoublepage
  % \@mainmatterfalse
  \pagenumbering{roman}
}

\newcommand\mainmatter{%
    \cleardoublepage
    % \@mainmattertrue
    \pagenumbering{arabic}
  }

\newcommand\backmatter{%
  \if@openright
    \cleardoublepage
  \else
    \clearpage
  \fi
  % \@mainmatterfalse
}

\makeatother

\title{Your Paper}
\author{You}

\begin{document}

%\includepdf{Cover_Page}


\frontmatter
\begin{abstract}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Abstract}    
\end{abstract}

\begingroup
  \hypersetup{hidelinks}
  \tableofcontents
\endgroup

\mainmatter
\chapter{Introduction}

\appendix
\chapter{MSE Reconstruction}
\chapter{Latent Encodings}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: `amsbook` etc. are using different mechanisms than `report`. Why are you linking a question about `amsbook`? Also, like in the other post from one hour ago: Please provide a compilable document. Apparently, you're using the `appendix` package ...

Comment: i have edited my code. I now use \appendix. I would like the content page to only show Appendix, instead of all the titles of each appendix

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's ugly, but it works.  Note: I used `\addappheadtotoc` instead of `\appendixpage` to save a page of text.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage[toc]{appendix}
\titleformat{\chapter}[display] {\normalfont\Huge\bfseries}{\chaptertitlename\ \thechapter}{0pt}{\Huge}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\linespread{1.5}   
\usepackage[a4paper,top=3cm,bottom=2cm,left=3cm,right=3cm,marginparwidth=1.75cm]{geometry}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[colorinlistoftodos]{todonotes}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tocbibind}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
  colorlinks=false,
  urlbordercolor=red
}
\makeatletter

\xpatchcmd{\titlepage}{\thispagestyle{empty}}{\pagestyle{plain}}{}{}% \xpatchcmd{\endtitlepage}{\setcounter{page}\@ne}{\cleardoublepage}{}{}% Remove the reset of page at the end of titlepage

\newcommand\frontmatter{%
  \cleardoublepage
  % \@mainmatterfalse
  \pagenumbering{roman}
}

\newcommand\mainmatter{%
    \cleardoublepage
    % \@mainmattertrue
    \pagenumbering{arabic}
  }

\newcommand\backmatter{%
  \if@openright
    \cleardoublepage
  \else
    \clearpage
  \fi
  % \@mainmatterfalse
}

\makeatother

\title{Your Paper}
\author{You}

\begin{document}

%\includepdf{Cover_Page}


\frontmatter
\begin{abstract}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Abstract}    
\end{abstract}

\begingroup
  \hypersetup{hidelinks}
  \tableofcontents
\endgroup

\mainmatter
\chapter{Introduction}

\appendix
\clearpage\addappheadtotoc% or \appendixpage
\refstepcounter{chapter}%
\chapter*{\appendixname~\thechapter\newline MSE Reconstruction}
\refstepcounter{chapter}%
\chapter*{\appendixname~\thechapter\newline Latent Encodings}
\end{document}
```

[image: demo]